# Wordpress как сделать меню?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать 3 меню на вордпрессе, добавил в functions.php:

```
add_theme_support('menus');
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top' =>  'Верхнее меню',
    'bottom1' =>'Нижнее меню1',
    'bottom2' => 'Нижнее меню2'

) );
```

Добавил в эти 3 меню свои пункты.
Прописал в footer.php и header.php менюшки

Пример из футер:

```
    <nav class="nav nav--footer">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php       wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'            => 'bottom1', 
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="nav__list">%3$s</ul>'
                    ) ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php       wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'            => 'bottom2', 
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="nav__list">%3$s</ul>'
                    ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

и на сайте у меня выводит везде три одинаковых меню. То есть везде меню **top**.
Что делаю не так? Подскажите

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вы зарегистрировали 3 области таким образом:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top' =>  'Верхнее меню',
    'bottom1' =>'Нижнее меню1',
    'bottom2' => 'Нижнее меню2'

) );
```

Так нужно писать если хотите вывести установленное в зарегистрированную областьменю:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'top',

) );
```

Так можно просто вывести меню по названию:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'  => 'Верхнее меню',

    ) );
```

Comment: Я бы еще отправил вот по [этой](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu) ссылке